# Python: maximize comparison performance of two byte arrays

Tags: python

I need to perform a fast comparison to check the equality of a portion of a byte list (generated from bytes retrieved on a socket) and a constant array in Python. It is possible to perform something similar to a binary subtraction?

```
list_1=[] #Byte list retrieved by reading a socket
array_2=b'\x30\x31'

if bytearray(list_1[0:8])==array_2:
   print("Arrays are equal!")
```

If this approach isn't possible, which is the most performant approach to compare?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? The first isn't a bytearray. If it were, you could just ``==`` the two.

Comment: Not sure about performance but if you want to compare the objects `array_1` and `array_2` you can do `"".join(map(chr, array_1)) == array_2`

Comment: `array_1` is a list. You'll need to convert it to a bytearray if you want to compare the two (and then simply use `array_1 == array_2`).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have a very long byte array and i need to compare a sub-array with a defined byte array

Comment: Well, if you *do* have two byte arrays then just ``array_1[0:8] == array_2`` – literally checking the equality of two arrays – will do. But even your most recent edit suggests you don't have two byte arrays.

Comment: If `array_1` is a static constant of some kind just convert it to a string (`array_1="".join(map(car, array_1))`) and then compare the two arrays as in @MisterMiyagi answer

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sorry, I specified the fact that the first object is a list, so I converted it to a byte array. Is this the best approach in terms of performances?

Comment: The best approach is to literally do what you are asking: comparing two bytes arrays for equality. If one of the operands isn't bytes, then ``bytes`` will fix that for you. But the whole question seems like a pileup of [XY Problems](https://xyproblem.info): a socket already provides ``bytes``, not "a byte list" as you have; ``bytes`` can already be compared for equality, not binary-subtracted as you have; performance shouldn't matter either way for such slices, yet this is what you have asked about… Apologies if this seems unhelpful. I merely want to avoid giving you another XY Problem on top.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi for performance reasons I'm reading byte chunks from a NON-BLOCKING socket: chunk+=socket.recv(MAX_CHUNK). This method reads all available bytes. Now, this approach makes chunk a list. For this reason, I ended up transforming the sub list using a byte array. It did the work. Thanks for your effort

Comment: No no no. Initialise ``chunk`` to empty bytes, i.e. ``chunk = b""``. You can then use ``chunk += socket.recv(MAX_CHUNK)`` to directly accumulate ``bytes`` *without* having an intermediate ``list``. There should be no need to go to a list and back again in your use-case.